# How to create relation data with TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I am trying to create and save a user's products.

Here's my attempt:

```
// userEntity.ts

import { Product } from '../product';

@Entity('user')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({
    unique: true
  })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(type => Product, product => product.user)
  @JoinTable()
  products: Product[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

```
// productEntity.ts

import { ProductCategory } from './productCategoryEntity';
import { User } from '../user';

@Entity('product')
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => ProductCategory, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: true
  })
  @JoinTable()
  category: ProductCategory;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.products)
  @JoinTable()
  user: User;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

`POST` at `http://localhost:4000/users/1/products`. This successfully creates a product but does not relate to the user.

```
// userPost.ts

export async function userPostProduct(
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const userRepository: Repository<User> = getManager().getRepository(User);
    const productRepository: Repository<Product> = getManager().getRepository(
      Product
    );

    // Load user by id
    const user = await userRepository.findOne(req.params.id);

    const { ...data } = req.body;

    const productToBeSaved = new Product();
    productToBeSaved.name = data.name;
    productToBeSaved.shortDescription = data.shortDescription;
    productToBeSaved.longDescription = data.longDescription;
    productToBeSaved.price = data.price;
    productToBeSaved.category = data.category;
    if (user) {
      productToBeSaved.user = user;
    }

    // Validate product entity
    const errors: ValidationError[] = await validate(productToBeSaved, {
      skipMissingProperties: true
    }); // Errors is and array of validation errors

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      // Return BAD REQUEST status code
      return next(createError(400, errors));
    } else {
      let product = await productRepository.save(productToBeSaved);
      // Return a CREATED status code and new product
      res.status(201).send({
        message: 'Product saved successfully',
        product
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // Return a BAD REQUEST status code and email already exists error
    return next(createError(400, err));
  }
}
```

I can not query user `1`'s products under `GET` `http://localhost:4000/users/1/products`

I also tried this:

```
// Build up entity product to be saved
const productToBeSaved = productRepository.create(req.body);
productToBeSaved.user = user;

if (user) {
  user.products = [productToBeSaved];
  await userRepository.save(user);
}
```

..but it said `productToBeSaved missing properties of Product[]: id, name, category, etc...`

So I changed:

```
if (user) {
  user.products = [...productToBeSaved];
  await userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Then it said `TypeError: productToBeSaved is not iterable`

Please help me, how do I create user's products relations.

Tech stack: TypeScript, Express, PostgreSQL, TypeORM

---

*I really want to use TypeORM, I wish they had better examples.*

Comment: Remove `@JoinTable()` decoractor, it's used only for many-to-many relations.

Comment: @aquz Thanks!!! It works! Anyway... is there any other way around without assigning every each data? `const { ...data } = req.body;`

Comment: You can use `const productToBeSaved = repository.create(data)` - https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/repository-api.md